# Duplicado sqlserver join

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle-11g

Hola buen dia tengo una duda, tengo una tabla que dice productos y una que dice equivalentes y ligados resulta que hago la consulta con joins donde esta asi:

```
Productos  Equivalentes   Ligados
00697000   MS-92692       MU-41309-P          
           MU-41309-P
```

pero en mi consulta me trae el resultado asi:

```
Producto            Equivalente         Ligado
00697000            MS-92692            MU-41309-P        
00697000            MU-41309-P          MU-41309-P
```

y entonces en en ligado me repite el producto MU-41309-P y no quiero que lo repita ya que solo esta una vez en la tabla ocupo algo asi:

```
Producto            Equivalente         Ligado
00697000            MS-92692            MU-41309-P        
00697000            MU-41309-P          NULL
```

Tengo el codigo asi:

```
    SELECT PROD.C1 AS CVE_PROD, EQUIVALENTES.C1 AS EQUIVALENTES, LIGADOS.C1 AS 
    LIGADOS
    FROM PRODUCTO AS PROD
    LEFT JOIN EQUIVALENTE AS EQUIVALENTES ON EQUIVALENTES.C2=PROD.C1
    LEFT JOIN LIGADO AS LIGADOS ON LIGADOS.C2=PROD.C1
   WHERE PROD.C1='00697000'
   ORDER BY PROD.C1
```

Comment: Por favor indícanos como son las estructuras de las tablas.

Comment: Usa INNER JOIN, ni lo dudes muchacho.

Comment: @Rostan TABLA PRODUCTO->ID_PRODUCTO, DESCRIPCION, TABLA EQUIVALENTES->ID_PRODUCTO,ID_PRODUCTO_EQUIV, TABLA LIGADOS->ID_PRODUCTO, ID_PRODUCTO_LIG, asi las tengo amigo

Comment: no encuentro como dices, ya intente con inner join y es le mismo resultado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el motivo por el cual te muestra el ligado 'MU-41309-P' en ambos registros es que el producto es '00697000' para ambos registros. si te mostrara un null como pides sería mentira, ya que el producto 00697000 si tiene un ligado. Te explico esto solo para que se entienda el "punto de vista" de la base de datos.

Una vez dicho esto, lo que pides sería algo así:

```
SELECT PROD.C1 AS CVE_PROD, EQUIVALENTES.C1 AS EQUIVALENTES, 
CASE WHEN Row_Number() Over(Partition By LIGADOS.C1 Order By PROD.C1) = 1 THEN LIGADOS.C1 ELSE '' END AS 
LIGADOS
FROM PRODUCTO AS PROD
LEFT JOIN EQUIVALENTE AS EQUIVALENTES ON EQUIVALENTES.C2=PROD.C1
LEFT JOIN LIGADO AS LIGADOS ON LIGADOS.C2=PROD.C1
WHERE PROD.C1='00697000'
ORDER BY PROD.C1
```

Prueba a ver, que como no lo puedo probar no se si me he equivocado en algo

Comment: Gracias amigo asi era si me funciono asi muchas gracias fue la solucion

Comment: ya no mas la aplique a mi query y funciono de maravilla